# How to mock db connection with Unittest for class with connection as context manager?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pyodbc

Here it is class with one of it's methods running when class is initializing:

```
class StatCollector:
    def __init__(self, poll_stat) -> None:
        self.polls = self.__get_polls()

    def __get_polls(self) -> Dict[str, Poll]:
        with pyodbc.connect(MSSQL_CONNECTION_PARAMS) as cnxn:
            polls = dict()
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()
            query = self.poll_stat.poll_ids_query_getter()
            cursor.execute(query, self.poll_stat.products_block)
            for poll in map(Poll._make, cursor.fetchall()):
                polls[poll.poll_id] = poll
        return polls
```

I want to test other methods of this class and my first goal is to fill `self.polls` with initial values with no real connection to db and using `__get_polls` method. My try:

```
@patch("pyodbc.connect")
class testStatCollector(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_initial_values_setted(self, mock_connect):
        cursor = MagicMock(name="my_cursor")
        cursor.fetchall.return_value = [("2", "А", "B")]
        cnxn = MagicMock(name="my_cnxn_mfk")
        cnxn.cursor.return_value = cursor
        mock_connect.return_value.__enter__ = cnxn
        self.test_class = PollsStatCollector(IVR)
        self.assertEqual(
            self.test_class.polls, {"2": Poll("2", "A", "B")}
        )
        self.assertIsInstance(self.test_class.period_start_time, datetime)
```

But `self.polls` are empty after execution. I got:
`AssertionError: {} != {'2': Poll(poll_id='2', product='A', products_block='B')}`

and I see in debug, that cnxn name = `my_cnxn_mfk` when `__get_polls` executing, but then cursor with default name = `<MagicMock name='my_cnxn_mfk().cursor()' id='1883689785424'>`.
So i guess that i make mistake in this part `cnxn.cursor.return_value = cursor`, but i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was here:

```
mock_connect.return_value.__enter__ = cnxn
```

Should be replaced with

```
mock_connect.return_value.__enter__.return_value = cnxn
```